# How to mutate multiple columns into new multiple columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate 3 columns into 3 new columns in a larger table (with more columns).
3 of the new columns depend on first existing 3 columns. 4th new column depends only on the 4th existing columns. Basically, I want to rotate coordinates of points (in columns x, y, z) in 3D space and store in a new columns (x_rot, y_rot, z_rot).

I could mutate 3 columns into 1 new column and repeat this for each dimension, which seems to be wasteful. It would be simpler, if my custom function would get 3 coordinates and return 3 rotated coordinates.

Here if I do this with a for loop:

```
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5), z = rnorm(5))
for(i in nrow(df){
    r = sqrt(df$x[i] ^ 2 + df$y[i] ^ 2 + df$z[i] ^ 2)
    phi = atan2(y = df$y[i], x = df$x[i])
    phi = phi + rotationAngle1
    theta = acos(df$z[i] / r)
    theta = theta + rotationAngle2
    df$x_ROT[i] = r * cos(phi) * sin(theta)
    df$y_ROT[i] = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
    df$z_ROT[i] = r * cos(theta)
}
```

or with **mutate_at** and function **rotate**:

```
rotate = function(x,y,z){
    r = sqrt(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + z ^ 2)
    phi = atan2(y = y, x = x)
    phi = phi + rotationAngle1
    theta = acos(z / r)
    theta = theta + rotationAngle2
    return(c(r * cos(phi) * sin(theta), r * sin(phi) * sin(theta),r * cos(theta))
    # OR
    return(list(x = r * cos(phi) * sin(theta), y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta), z = r * cos(theta))
}
```

How, can I do this with dplyr? How can I formulate df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate_at(???)

Comment: If x', 'y', 'z' are column names passed as string to function, then the second line `df$` would be `df[[x]]` or `df[[y]]`

Comment: ah sorry, have bunch of code open to try different things. I have corrected. x y z are actual coordinates. rotate function should be passed on mutate_at.

Comment: What is `rotationAngle2`.  Also, regarding the  two `return`, which one you are using

Comment: A constant in this case. Just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can use `mutate_at` where `f1`, `f2` are the functions used for rotation

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         mutate_at(vars(x, y, z),   list(rot =  f1)) %>%
         mutate(col4_rot = f2(col4))
```

---

In the `devel` version, use `mutate` with `across`

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
           mutate(across(vars(x, y, z),  f1, names = "{col}_rot"), 
                   col4_rot = f2(col4))
```

#### Update

Based on the updated function, we can use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

pmap_dfr(df, rotate) %>% 
     rename_all(~ str_c(., '_rot')) %>% 
     bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#        x       y      z   x_rot    y_rot   z_rot
#    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 -0.303   1.20   -0.503 -0.0457  0.00799 -1.34  
#2 -0.0662 -0.599   1.45   1.35   -0.793    0.0405
#3  0.239   0.953   1.49  -1.39    1.09    -0.288 
#4 -0.490   0.0106 -0.622  0.157   0.333   -0.701 
#5  0.554   1.08    0.761 -0.748   0.928   -0.802
```

where

```
rotationAngle2 <- 20
rotate <- function(x,y,z){
     r = sqrt(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + z ^ 2)
     phi = atan2(y = y, x = x)
     phi = phi + rotationAngle2
     theta = acos(z / r)
     theta = theta + rotationAngle2   
     return(list(x = r * cos(phi) * sin(theta), 
                 y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta),
                 z = r * cos(theta)))
 }
```

---

It is also possible with `mutate`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(out = list(rotate(x, y, z))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(c(out))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#        x       y      z   x_rot    y_rot   z_rot
#    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 -0.303   1.20   -0.503 -0.0457  0.00799 -1.34  
#2 -0.0662 -0.599   1.45   1.35   -0.793    0.0405
#3  0.239   0.953   1.49  -1.39    1.09    -0.288 
#4 -0.490   0.0106 -0.622  0.157   0.333   -0.701 
#5  0.554   1.08    0.761 -0.748   0.928   -0.802
```

Or another option is to return the `list` in `summarise` and then do the `unnest_wider` and `unnest`

```
df %>%
    summarise(out = list(rotate(x, y, z))) %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(out)) %>% 
    unnest(cols = everything()) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#        x       y      z   x_rot    y_rot   z_rot
#    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 -0.303   1.20   -0.503 -0.0457  0.00799 -1.34  
#2 -0.0662 -0.599   1.45   1.35   -0.793    0.0405
#3  0.239   0.953   1.49  -1.39    1.09    -0.288 
#4 -0.490   0.0106 -0.622  0.157   0.333   -0.701 
#5  0.554   1.08    0.761 -0.748   0.928   -0.802
```

where

```
rotate <- function(x,y,z){
     r = sqrt(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + z ^ 2)
     phi = atan2(y = y, x = x)
     phi = phi + rotationAngle2
     theta = acos(z / r)
     theta = theta + rotationAngle2   
     return(list(x_rot = r * cos(phi) * sin(theta), 
                 y_rot = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta), 
                 z_rot = r * cos(theta)))
 }
```

Comment: Does f1 return multiple values in a vector?

Comment: @Genom Without a small reproducible example or your function, it is difficult to comment

Comment: Sorry, I was aware of the solution you provided but as far as I understand, this works with f1 accepting an argument and returning a single value. However, rotating in 3D space involved all 3 values (x, y, z) and gives/returns new x, y, z. I will try to provide an example.

Comment: @Genom if it is more than one element as output, you can wrap it as a `list` and then use `unnest_wider` for 3 more columns, but I would like to know the function used and some examples

Comment: I have provided an example.

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible with dplyr's mutate?

Comment: Then I run it, I get this:
# A tibble: 5 x 6
       x       y      z x_rot     y_rot     z_rot    
   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 -0.745 -0.0794  0.665 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
2 -0.533 -0.735  -0.668 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
3  0.560 -0.617  -0.603 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
4  0.111  1.51    0.237 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
5 -1.10   0.141   1.02  <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
_rot columns have vectors with 5 elements.

Comment: @Genom Based on your function, I get 3 columns new i.e. _rot columns and it is binded with the original dataset, therefore 6 columns

Comment: @Genom are you using the same functions (I modified your rotate), also I have `rowwise` before `mutate`

Comment: @Genom I added one more option.  Hope it helps

Comment: I tried will 4 different combinations of function, each one gives either too many columns or vectors as values in cells. However, last example worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Genom It could be something related to the package version

Comment: I wasn't aware of unnest. Now I will look into this more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out!!!

In my case, I did:

`mutate (log2 (across (starts_with ("ratio"), .names = "log2_{.col}")))`

So I would transform only the columns whose names started with "ratio" into logarithms. The new columns will have the same name as the originals *and* the prefix "log2_".