# Looking for a way to create a "median split" variable for several variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset which contains about 40 different variables. Now I would like to create a new variable indicating whether each observation is above or below the median.

I managed to create a new variable "var1_mediansplit" from the existing "var1" (values 1 for below median, 2 for everything else):

`mydata$var1_mediansplit <- ifelse(mydata$var1 < median(mydata$var1), mydata$var1_mediansplit <- "1", mydata$var1_mediansplit <- "2"`

I am looking for a way to run it through several variables (with a loop, I would guess). I appreciate any help!

Edit: The solution from jblood94 worked for me, so thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mutate multiple columns into new multiple columns with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036146/how-to-mutate-multiple-columns-into-new-multiple-columns-with-dplyr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `colMedians` and `eachrow` from the `Rfast` package:

```
library(Rfast)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(4000), ncol = 40)) # dummy data
m <- as.matrix(df)
df2 <- as.data.frame((eachrow(m, colMedians(m), "-") >= 0) + 1)
```

Detailed explanation:

1. `colMedians(m)` returns the median of each column (a vector of
   length 40).
2. `eachrow` takes a matrix for the first argument, a vector for the second argument (with the same length as the number of columns in the matrix), and an operator for the third argument. Each row of the matrix has the vector applied to it according to the operator. So here, the `colMedians(m)` vector is subtracted from each row of `m`.
3. The result of `eachrow` is compared to `0` (`FALSE` if it is less than `0`, `TRUE` otherwise).
4. Operating on a logical with a numeric will coerce it to numeric: `FALSE + 1` = `1`, and `TRUE + 1` = `2`.

Comment: I'm coming back to this after a break from my project and now I'm having trouble understanding the eachrow function. Could you explain what eachrow does here. I don't understand the operator "-" and >= 0) + 1. Thanks!

Comment: See the detailed explanation I added just now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate it, consider this:

```
v <- c(1:100)
x <- median(v)
y <- v >= x
```